# Automation Unit Test Cases in SPFX Extensions using Jest

Tags: automation, jestjs, sharepoint-online, spfx

I want to automate unit test cases for SPFX using Jest Framework. I am able to write the test cases but do not know how to get SharePoint context in jest text cases to get properties from SharePoint. Any pointer will be of great help. TIA